# datetimepicker plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using this plugin [datetimepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) which uses jquery ui. It gives this error in firebug

```
$.datepicker undefined
$.datepicker._base_selectDate = $.datepicker._selectDate; jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js (line 941)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a version of jquery UI which includes the datepicker, and load that script on your page before the datetimepicker.